# terraform outputs: Take output of aws_vpc_peering_connection resource and loop to add aws_route

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating a new vpc using the vpc module. This new vpc will beed to be peered with multiple other vpcs and also the route tables for all vpcs will need to be updated with the route and the correct peering connection as the target

I have a aws_vpc_peering_connection resource which is currently creating two peering connections. It is getting the vpc_id of the vpcs I want to peer with through a data source.

```
data "aws_vpcs" "peer_vpcs" {
  tags = {
    environment = "test"
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "peer_vpcs" {
  count = length(data.aws_vpcs.peer_vpcs.ids)
  id    = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.peer_vpcs.ids)[count.index]
}


##### PEERING CONNECTION ######
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection" "vpc_peering" {
  count = length(data.aws_vpcs.peer_vpcs.ids)
  peer_vpc_id   = module.vpc.vpc_id
  vpc_id        = data.aws_vpc.peer_vpcs[count.index].id
  auto_accept   = true

  accepter {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }

  requester {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.cluster_name}-vpc to vpc"
  }
}
```

The above creates 2 peering connections because there are two vpc that presently exist with the "test" tag.

`aws_vpc_peering_connection.vpc_peering[0]` and `aws_vpc_peering_connection.vpc_peering[1]`

I now want to add routes to the applicable route tables but ensure that the correct vpc_peering_connection_id is being passed as the target for each route table while also the correct route table id is being passed. I want to do this all through the use of data sources and outputs from previous resources rather than hard coding any vpc id etc. Currently the aws_route resource looks like this and failing.

```
resource "aws_route" "peering_routes" {
  count                     = length(data.aws_route_tables.peer_rtbs.ids)
  route_table_id            = tolist(data.aws_route_tables.rts.ids)[count.index]
  destination_cidr_block    = module.vpc.vpc_cidr_block
  vpc_peering_connection_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection.vpc_peering[count.index].id

  depends_on = [
    aws_vpc_peering_connection.vpc_peering
  ]
}
```

This is how I am getting the route tables of the newly created vpc

```
data "aws_route_tables" "rts" {
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}
```

this is how I am getting the route tables of the vpcs that match the "test" tag

```
data "aws_route_tables" "peer_rtbs" {
  count = length(data.aws_vpcs.peer_vpcs.ids)
  vpc_id    = tolist(data.aws_vpcs.peer_vpcs.ids)[count.index]
}
```

I feel like there are two items that need to match. The route table id and the correct peering connection id for that route table as a target.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the current code? Any errors?